# DNS for netdevices

Tags: dns

I apologize for my English. So, for example, there is a cisco switch with the following config: 
***hostname cs 
ip domain name office.local 
ip name-server XXXXXXXX*** 
Is it possible to make that the entry "cs.office.local" automatically appears in the dns zone office.local? Which dns server can do it ?